# spring boot always using the same profile

Tags: maven, spring-boot, maven-profiles, spring-profiles, spring-properties

I am using spring boot 1.5.2, and using profiles but I found a very strange thing.

my spring boot resources folder like this:
[image]

configs in application.yml

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: @profileActive@
```

application-dev.yml

```
spring:
  profiles: dev
    datasource:
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
      url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1
      username: root
      password:
server:
  port: 8080
```

application-test.yml

```
spring:
  profiles: test
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db2
    username: root
    password:

server:
  port: 8081
```

my pom.xml, just only include resources part and profile part.

```
<!-- profile -->
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <build.profile.id>dev</build.profile.id>
            <profileActive>dev</profileActive>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <properties>
            <build.profile.id>test</build.profile.id>
            <profileActive>test</profileActive>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <build.profile.id>prod</build.profile.id>
            <profileActive>prod</profileActive>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>


<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>application-${profileActive}.yml</include>
                <include>application.yml</include>
                <include>templates/*</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>

    </resources>
```

I am now trying to use **test profile** , found that everything is oK , `@profileActive@` has been replace to `test`;

```
mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Ptest
```

It looks like everything is Ok.

[image]

but when I try to run the jar, it always using **dev** profile, although `application.yml` shows we now using `test or prod` profile.

[image]

I don't know where is wrong in my yml configs. And I try to include all the profile configs in just one application.yml file. But the application still using `dev` profile.

fully configs in one application.yml file

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: @profileActive@

---
spring:
  profiles: dev
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1
  username: root
  password:

server:
  port: 8080

---
spring:
  profiles: test
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db2
    username: root
    password:

server:
  port: 8081

---
spring:
  profiles: prod

server:
  port: 9000
```

finally, I try to using **properties** files, all of my configs works fine, when I run my application can use the right profile.

And Now, I just want to know what's wrong with my yml configs.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you put all the pieces together in a Git repository to make it easy to see _exactly_ how you've configured things?

Comment: I just created a simple project exactly like you defined yours. Everything works like expected. Can you try to run the jar outside of intelliJ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

finally, I found the reason.

my project is a multiple module maven project。

one module I am using `yml` format,

and other is `property` format.

when I make the two module both the yml format, everything ok.

thanks all of you! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to run your jar like

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=test yourapp.jar
```

or replace @profileActive@ on the name of the profile you need.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be, that when spring boot reads your application.yml, it already made the decision to fall back to the default profile. From there on, i think, it is to late to switch profiles.

What you can try, is to define your *spring.profiles.active* property in a configuration file called "bootstrap.yml". This may do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your description with `spring-boot-starter-web` as an additional dependency to be able to start a small application.

Everything works as expected. If I run `mvn clean package -Ptest` the `test` profile will be activated. Same with the other profiles. I put all profiles together into one `yml` file, comment out `<include>application-${profileActive}.yml</include>` and it works, too.

Everything work as expected, too, when I execute the JAR file like you from a parent file system path. When I execute another Maven build with another profile at the same time and restart the application the new profile will be used.

If you'r using `mvn clean package` with another profile than `dev` it shouldn't be possible that any `application-dev.yml` is in the produced JAR. Without `clean` and different builds with different Maven profiles they will be all in the JAR.

Which OS do you use? Is it possible that something holds a file handle on your JAR file and it won't be replaced? But this should be signaled in your Maven build.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally do the following:

1) remove this from your application.yaml (because you can just set a JVM property for this)

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: @profileActive@
```

2) remove the profile specific header from each of your profile specific yaml files. You don't need it as the profile is based on the file suffix e.g. remove this:

```
spring:
  profiles: dev
```

3) As Oleg said, just run your task with Dspring.profiles.active=Whatever