# spring boot - last profile always used

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

Spring boot consistently selects the last profile in my application.yml file, no matter how I order them. Please help. If I tear out any more hair, I'll have none left.

- Using spring-boot-starter-parent 1.5.1.RELEASE
- Maven 3.2.5
- There is only one application.yml in my artifact.
- I see this in my log: **o.s.boot.SpringApplication.logStartupProfileInfo 641 - The following profiles are active: DEV**

Here is my application.yml:

```
server:
  context-path: /MyApplicationUI
  port: 8480

---
#   LOCAL 
spring:
  profiles: LOCAL
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
    username: #insert username# 
    encrypted-password: #insert password#
    url: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver:blah blah stuff here;
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
    show-sql: true

---
#   DEVELOPMENT 
spring:
  profiles: DEV
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
    username: #insert username# 
    encrypted-password: #insert password#
    url: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver:blah blah stuff here;
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
    show-sql: true

---
#   TEST 
spring:
  profiles: TEST
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
    username: #insert username# 
    encrypted-password: #insert password#
    url: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver:blah blah stuff here;
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
    show-sql: true
```

I'm loading the encrypted password via my own DatasourceConfig.java:

```
public class DatasourceConfig {

    @Value("${encrypted-password}")
    private String encryptedPassword;

    /**
     * Sets up the datasource with Spring - decrypting password first
     * 
     * @return Datasource
     */
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource setupDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().password(getSecurePassword()).build();
    }

    /**
     * Decrypts encryptedPassword property
     * 
     * @return decryptedPassword
     */
    private String getSecurePassword() {
        System.out.println("Encrypted password = " + encryptedPassword);
        return new AESEncryptionUtils().decryptString(encryptedPassword);
}
...
```

I do NOT have multiple modules per: [spring boot always using the same profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43295904/spring-boot-always-using-the-same-profile)

A thousand thanks-you's to whomever can offer insight.

Comment: seems odd, have you verified the active profile via the /env endpoint if you have the actuator dependencies?

Comment: @Eric any solution found for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This YAML file looks more concise:

```
server:
  context-path: /MyApplicationUI
  port: 8480
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
    username: #insert username# 
    encrypted-password: #insert password#
    url: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver:blah blah stuff here;
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
    show-sql: true
  profiles:
    active: default, local
---
# DEVELOPMENT 
spring:
  profiles: DEV
  datasource:
    username: #insert username# 
    encrypted-password: #insert password#
    url: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver:blah blah stuff here;
---
# TEST 
spring:
  profiles: TEST
  datasource:
    username: #insert username# 
    encrypted-password: #insert password#
    url: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver:blah blah stuff here;
```

You don't need to repeat everything all the time, just "the parts" that change between profiles. By default, with this configuration, the profile(s) that will be used are: `local` and/or `default`.

If you want to use a different one you have to pass this switch `--spring.profiles.active=DEV` (or the identifier of the one you want) to the artifact on the command-line (or a script, Docker container, etc).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  My yaml was originally more condensed, but I changed it when I was grasping at straws for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out what caused this problem.  I had to do a work-around instead.  I switched to using property files instead of a yaml.  I used a separate property file for each environment, and then explicitly loaded the appropriate property for the environment.  I had to do this for my datasourceConfig.java.  Not ideal, but it worked.

```
String env1[] = this.environment.getActiveProfiles();
InputStream propertiesFile = DatasourceConfig.class.getClassLoader()
   .getResourceAsStream("application-" + env1[0] + ".properties");
prop.load(propertiesFile);
```

Comment: Did you try the YAML file that I wrote in one of the answer(s)? I think what you were missing was the `profiles: active: default` setting